# Receiving data from Network C++

Tags: c++, python-2.7, sockets, networking

I have a python function to send data over the network by data gram socket.In the receiver end i have to use c++ to receive that data  But the receiver can't receive any meaningful data.What should be used to get the string in the exact format it was sent?

Python code

```
def send(self, command):
        segments = command.split() # split command on spaces
        if len(segments) < 5 or segments[1] not in self.hosts or segments[2] not in self.hosts: # sanity check
            print('invalid arguments')
            return
        else:
            h1 = map(int, segments[1].split('.'))# segment 1 contains a IP address
            h2 = map(int, segments[2].split('.'))# segment 2 contains an IP address
            fmt = '4s4B4Bh' + segments[3] + 's'# segemt 3 is string length segment 4 is a string
            buf = struct.pack(fmt, segments[0], h1[0], h1[1], h1[2], h1[3], h2[0], h2[1], h2[2], h2[3], int(segments[3]), ' '.join(segments[4:]))
            print('sending to {0}'.format(segments[1])) # print a message before sending to source
            self.s.sendto(buf, (segments[1], self.port)) # send to source
            #self.s.sendto(command, (segments[1], self.port)) # send to source
```

C++ code

```
bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, &addrlen);
        //print(buffer);
        if(bytes_received==-1)
        {
            perror("recvfrom");
            printf("error %s\n",strerror(errno));
        }

        printf("[%s:%hu]: %s \n", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr), ntohs(client_address.sin_port), buffer);
```

All the sockets are created properly

Comment: Show the declaration of `buffer`.  And I suspect `sizeof(buffer)` is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have a specification for the data format that the Python code is using? If not, you should start by making one.

Comment: buffer is a char array, its size 1024. Isn't it enough to receive a message like "send 192 168 10 1 11 Hello_world "

Comment: When you say it can't receive any meaningful data...do you mean that the recvfrom is returning, bytes_received is correct, but the content is wrong somehow? Do you have an example of sent data vs received data?

Comment: sent data - "send 192 168 10 1 192 168 10 2 11 Hello_world ", Received Data- "send ???????                         "  only the "send" part is received properly other part is garbage. @ struthersneil

Comment: Out of interest, do you initialize your buffer with zeroes? You're passing buffer to printf and asking it to treat it as a string with %s, no problem, but it will expect a zero to terminate the string. It could be you're printing out garbage from your uninitialized buffer. Try setting `buffer[bytes_received] = 0` after you check that it's not -1.

Comment: Tools to use when doing network programming: wireshark and debugger.  With wireshark you know exactly what is sent on the wire.

Comment: buffer was initialized , and i have used "buffer[bytes_received] = 0" but the problem is still there.

Comment: Try dumping the buffer contents as hex to see exactly what you received, e.g...https://gist.github.com/anonymous/584b9e4aad2c4aa4851171e546c93e1a

Comment: You can also take your C++ program out of the debugging loop altogether by using netcat to listen on the port and dump out whatever it receives to the console, e.g. `nc -l localhost 9000 | hexdump` (where 9000 is your receiving port)

Answer (score 0):

If you receive something like "send ???????" I'd expect encoding problems during sending. '?' is 0x3F (dec 63) which usually comes from characters out of basic ASCII (less then 127) table. I'm not familiar with python, but can you ensure you use proper (e.g. UTF-8, for sure not UTF-16/32 and perhaps not ASCII) encoding while transforming python string into byte array?